# how to send a file whole via a python socket without reading it line by line?

Tags: python, list, file, sockets, tcp

I was making a private chat application with python, where the text logs will be encrypted and uploaded into the server, since the chat logs are a very private file, I wanted to store the file whole in the server via sockets without having to send it chunk by chunk.

```
import socket

def send_file(file_path, conn):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        data = file.read(1024)  # Read and send file in chunks
        while data:
            conn.send(data)
            data = file.read(1024)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 12345))
server_socket.listen(1)

print("Server listening on port 12345")

conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
print("Connection from:", addr)

send_file('example.txt', conn)  # Replace 'example.txt' with your file path

conn.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: You're not reading line by line. You're reading in blocks of 1024 bytes. You can send it in one call with `conn.send(file.read())`

Comment: it seems my understanding of the sending concept was wrong, you solution worked ! thank you.

Comment: update : what if the file content exceeds the 1024 block size ?

Comment: What makes you think there's a 1024 block size limit?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't have blocks.